# Python row, column, matrix trouble

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program with with a given

```
matrix = [['A', 'B', 'C'], 
          ['D', 'E', 'F'], 
          ['G', 'H', 'I']]
```

I'm trying to write a code so that I can define the coordinates for each value so that if I if my command is get_coordinate('any value in matrix') it will print out the row and column from the matrix.

I'm having difficulty defining the rows and columns to get this code to work. What I'm really looking for is how can I write row = row of matrix, and column = column of matrix.

Comment: I've tried: def get_coordinate(letter):
    row = matrix[0,2][:]
    column = matrix[:][0,2]
    return row, column

Comment: you should edit your question and add what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try this,

```
def getLoc(matrix, elem):
    row , col = 0 , 0
    for a in [j for i in matrix for j in i]:
        if a == elem:
            return row / len(matrix), col % len(matrix)
        col += 1
        row += 1
```

Comment: will it be a similar method to get the reverse? find_char(key, row, col): char = key[row + col * 3]     return char