# Python characters within a matrix

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python row, column, matrix trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680953/python-row-column-matrix-trouble)

I'm writing a python program with with a given

```
matrix = [['A', 'B', 'C'], 
          ['D', 'E', 'F'], 
          ['G', 'H', 'I']]
```

I'm trying to write a code so that I can define the coordinates for each value in the matrix. I have this to define the rows and column to get a coordinate:

```
def getLoc(key, elem):
    row , col = 0 , 0
    for a in [j for i in key for j in i]:
        if a == elem:
            return row / len(key), col % len(key)
        col += 1
        row += 1
```

That works to give me the coordinate for the letter but to work from the coordinate to get the letter I use:

```
def find_char(key, row, col):
    for a in [j for i in key for j in i]:
        if a == row , col = 0 , 0
            return elem
```

This doesn't give me a character. Why not?

Comment: Please reformat the code. It's impossible to read that in-line code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think find char should / could look like this

```
def find_char(key, row, col):
    return key[row][col]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `key[row][col]` for accessing the value (I assume you're passing matrix in as key). The reason your code fails is because there is no elem passed in, so it returns nothing.